# How to style a div with a window location

Tags: jquery, css

I have this code

```
<div onclick="location.href='www.example.com'">
  <!--Content Here-->
</div>
<div>
  <!--Content Here-->
</div>
```

I know that I can use an inline CSS styling for the `div` with `location.href` to do something like

```
<div onclick="location.href='www.example.com';" style="cursor:pointer;">
  <!--Content Here-->
</div>
```

Although I would rather not use this method, as inline styling is terrible to change later

I can also add a class that `div` to work for styling such as

```
<div class="location" onclick="location.href='www.example.com';">
  <!--Content Here-->
</div>
```

```css
.location {cursor:pointer;}
```

But I was wondering if there was some way to use CSS to only target `div` with a `location.href`. I can't use something like `div:first-child`, because I want to use an external stylesheet to style these, so there has to be a way to only target ones with `location.href`. If not purely CSS, is there a way to do this using jQuery?

Comment: What was the problem with adding the class to it like you did in the end?

Comment: @nbrooks I would rather not have to edit my HTML to do this

Comment: @CodyGuldner But instead have inline JavaScript? What would you think most Web Developers would chose out of those two?

Comment: @MackieeE I would have to use multiple different classes such as `.location1` `.location2`, which is not very effective

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

This is a jquery solution, thought you are looking for that.

Sure, you can look for attributes and their values:

```
$('div[onclick^="location.href"]').css('color', 'red');
```

Looks for a div with attribute `onlick` starting with `location.href`

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/7ME5a/

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm sure whatever you're doing, this isn't the best approach.

Solution:

```
div[onclick^="location.href"] {cursor: pointer;}
```

A better solution is to leave the class on the element, and bind a click handler using jQuery:

```
$('div.location').click(function () {
    location.href = ...;
});
```

Your css remains as:

```
div.location {cursor: pointer; }
```

Comment: @cody Inline click handlers are generally undesirable, and then if you make your css reliant on that, that will have to change whenever your click handler changes. What's your problem with the adding `class='location'`?

Comment: Because each `div` with `location.href` has a different location it is linked to. I would totally agree with you if it was multiple `div` on the same location